# Which JavaScript, Grails and/or Grails framework produces these validation tooltip? (pictures included)

Tags: html, forms, validation, required

I was asked to refactor an application and to change the texts of the tooltips that the (client-side) validation provides. I am, however, totally at loss at identifying which framework is being used (and people who've worked on this project previously aren't available for questions). 
What I found out so far is that the application consists of things called grails, groovy and kickstarter with bootstrap.

Those tooltips are visually unique - look (and text, too!) differ on every major browser. Could someone maybe make do with these clues and identify from these picture the framework said application uses for client-side validation?

Validation tooltip as displayed in Chrome:

[image: Validation tooltip as displayed in Chrome]

Validation tooltip as displayed in Firefox:

[image: Validation tooltip as displayed in Firefox]

Validation tooltip as displayed in IE:

[image: Validation tooltip as displayed in IE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a library, this is the browser using HTML5 validation. That's why it looks different in each browser.

You may want to [look at](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp) some of the new form attributes in HTML5, in particular `required`.

Comment: Correct. Just did an image search on "tooltip html5 validation" and the results look like what I came across.